# Find Duplicates in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, group-by

My table contains multiple `lots (LOT_ID)` and each lot contains multiple `products(PRODUCT_ID)` and there are multiple `orders (ORDER_ID)` under each Product. I would like to know the `order ID’s` which are repeated for multiple `products` for a given `LOT`

```
S.NO    LOT_ID  Product_ID  Order_ID
1        101    P108        90001
2        101    P109        90001
3        101    P110        80900
4        102    S189        10098
5        102    S234        10087
6        102    S465        10098
7        102    S342        10050
8        103    L109        20090
9        103    L110        20098
10       103    L111        20020
```

Desired result

```
S.NO     LOT_ID  Product_ID Order_ID
1         101     P108       90001
2         101     P109       90001
3         102     S189       10098
4         102     S465       10098
```

Comment: I think you should find the solution already posted in `stackoverflow` or by `googling`, you should search a lot before posting question, otherwise you might post a duplicate question which will **cost you (10) or more points**.

Comment: A simple select like this is all you need: `SELECT [S.NO], LOT_ID, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID FROM myTable T WHERE ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM myTable WHERE LOT_ID = T.LOT_ID GROUP BY ORDER_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);`

Comment: Above code is displaying the results for multiple orders, but I would like to know the orders which are repeated for multiple products, have a look at the example I mentioned in my Question. Order ID's ( 90001 & 10098 ) repeated twice for multiple products under the same LOT. so result set should only display the LOT_ID, PRODUCT_ID related to these orders

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply group by on order_id first and you will get the result set. Please check the answer posted, However I haven't run this.

```
select LOT_ID, Product_ID, Order_ID  
from <tableName>
where Order_ID IN (SELECT Order_ID FROM <tableName> where LOT_ID in (101,102) 
GROUP BY Order_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: If it were possible for an order ID to exist against different lot IDs, this would produce undesired results. Also, presumably more than just lots 101/102 need to be checked against. Better would be to alias the table in the from statement and refer to it in the in statement (see my comment).

Answer (score 0):

count repeats and then select the quantity you need

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by t.LOT_ID, t.Product_ID, t.Order_ID) as c
        , count(*) over (partition by t.LOT_ID,  t.Order_ID) as c2
    from t
```

When count of unique strings is not equal count of unique Lots and Orders - is your case.